# display image variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php variable called $image which holds the contents of a medium blob from a mySQL server and I'm trying you output it using PHP5.

When I just use the code:

```
echo $image;
```

it just output a page full of ASCII characters.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the correct `Content-Type` header.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Comment: when I test this on certain browsers (safari and IE) the image is downloaded instead of being displayed, do you know any reason this might be occuring?