# display image variable in php code

Tags: php, image

I am trying to display an image from a variable in php. Followed [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158631/display-image-variable) but i get this instead of image

`�PNG  IHDRBMyAPLTE����ٟ�IDAT�c��Z8Y]��Ðf�T%����IEND�B`�`

This is my code.

```
$tt_image = imagecreate( 100, 50 ); /* width, height */
$background = imagecolorallocatealpha( $tt_image, 0, 0, 255, 127 ); /* In RGB colors- (Red, Green, Blue, Transparency ) */
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $tt_image );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $tt_image );
```

Comment: Can you show full code? Including the way you get png file into `$image`.

Comment: @DeDee please check updated answer

Comment: @SubinThomas on the webpage instead of displaying Image , �PNG  IHDRBMyAPLTE����ٟ�IDAT�c��Z8Y]��Ðf�T%����IEND�B�`
 is printed

Comment: @SubinThomas I need to display an image.

Comment: @RyanVincent can you give an example

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

This code is checked and found working. You have to edit your image before displaying. And put header just above displaying image.

```
    $tt_image = imagecreate( 100, 100 ); /* width, height */
$background = imagecolorallocatealpha( $tt_image, 0, 0, 255, 78 );  //fill some color
header ('Content-type: image/png'); //image type header
imagepng($tt_image, NULL, 0);       //disply image
imagedestroy($tt_image);            //destroy image
```